# CakePHP 2.4.6 ModelName case sensitivity in view

Tags: php, cakephp, model, uppercase

I'm struggling with what appears to be a very strange problem, at least, for me.
I've been trying to look around for this, but i cannot see anything that points to the same problem, so please forgive me if this topic has already been answered before.

The problem that i'm having is that some results i get from the database, are comming on the array sometimes with the model name with the first letter in uppercase and sometimes lowercase.

**For example:**

**In my Controller:**

```
$this->set('local', $this->Local->findById(5);
$this->set('curso', $this->Curso->findById(10);
```

**In my View:**

```
<?php echo $local['Local']['nombre'];?>
<?php echo $local['Curso']['nombre'];?>
```

**Results:**

The first "echo" works fine.

The second one says: 
Notice (8): Undefined index: Curso

Then, if I use "echo $local['curso']['nombre']" (**curso** is lowercase), it works fine.

**Mode information: **

1- This problem happens in my local machine. The same code works fine on the production server.
2- I don't know if it has something to do in here, but i copy my Local and Curso models:

```
class Local extends AppModel  {
    public $useTable = 'locales';

    public $validate = array(
        'email' => 'email'
    );
}

class Curso extends AppModel  {
    public $useTable = 'cursos';
    public $belongsTo = 'area';

}
```

Hope you get to understand my problem.
Thanks everybody!

Comment: Can you just show us `$local` the data?

Comment: Don't you think it should be actually

<?php echo $curso['Curso']['nombre'];?>

Comment: Dave, what do you mean by showing the data? What it echoes or you want to see the print_r of the variable?

Comment: Abhishek, sorry. I wanted to say $curso['Curso']['nombre']. I just copied that from the first line, but i-m actually using $curso['Curso']['nombre'] as you say.

Comment: `public $belongsTo = 'area';` => Please respect conventions. `Area` is the correct alias/name. Mind your casing when writing code - this will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks mark. Somehow that doesn't work for my solution. I'm not really sure why, but i'll keep it in mind on the next developments! Thanks a lot everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem!

I don't really know why it was working on the production server but not in my development environment (that still remains a mystery lol)

The solution was to use in my controller's action the following line of code:

```
$this->loadModel("Curso");
```

Hope this can help others with the same annoying problem.